# Filter data from two pandas DataFrame when columns match

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the two following `pandas.DataFrame`, `df0` and `df1` :

```
import pandas as pd

# 1st data set
dat0 = [['A0', 'B0', 'C0', 'case0', 1],
        ['A0', 'B2', 'C0', 'case0', 2],
        ['A1', 'B0', 'C0', 'case0', 3],
        ['A1', 'B1', 'C0', 'case0', 4],
        ['A0', 'B0', 'C1', 'case0', 5]]
df0 = pd.DataFrame(dat0, columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colCase', 'colVal'])

# 2nd data set
dat1 = [['A0', 'B1', 'C2', 'case1', 6],
        ['A0', 'B2', 'C2', 'case1', 7],
        ['A1', 'B0', 'C2', 'case1', 8],
        ['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'case1', 9]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dat1, columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colCase', 'colVal'])
```

I am trying to get all the lines that, for each couple of columns (A, B) have a value for both case0 and case1 (ie a value in each DF).

In case it matters, I cannot have "duplicate" lines in the DataFrames: the set (A, B, C, case) is unique in each DF.

So I would like to reach a code that would look like:

```
# Merge the DataFrames
df = pd.concat([df0, df1])  # maybe concat is not a good starting point

for a in ['A0', 'A1', 'A2']:
    for b in ['B0', 'B1', 'B2']:
        table = my_great_function(df, a, b)
        if table:
            print '---'
            print table
```

And get the following result:

```
---
  colA colB colC colCase  colVal
1   A0   B2   C0   case0       2
1   A0   B2   C2   case1       7
---
  colA colB colC colCase  colVal
2   A1   B0   C0   case0       3
2   A1   B0   C2   case1       8
```

Note I don't want to get results where only one line appears, nor where two or more lines appear with the same case.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something similar to this. Modify the condition accordingly if that is not exactly what you want (here each g represents a sub data frame with a unique combination of colA and colB):

```
for _, g in df.groupby(["colA", "colB"]):
    case_lst = g.colCase.tolist()
    if 'case0' in case_lst and 'case1' in case_lst:
        print("--------")
        print(g)

--------
  colA colB colC colCase  colVal
1   A0   B2   C0   case0       2
1   A0   B2   C2   case1       7
--------
  colA colB colC colCase  colVal
2   A1   B0   C0   case0       3
2   A1   B0   C2   case1       8
```

Comment: Seems great. I try as soon as possible.

Comment: Exactly what needed! Thx.